# How to get EF6 to generate efficient in(...) queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

So... EF6 is creating a horribly inefficient query. I have a query that goes against a data source with three different types of addresses. I have a list of address ids that are potential duplicates of the new one a user is trying to use. Ideally, I would like this query to check if either of several address ids are in the given set of provided ids. Currently this query:

```
return await _tickets.Where(t =>
    t.Metadata is SIFTEscalationMetadata && (
        addesses.Any(a => a == (t.Metadata as SIFTEscalationMetadata).Address.Id) ||
        addesses.Any(a => a == (t.Metadata as SIFTEscalationMetadata).AddressEntered.Id) ||
        addesses.Any(a => a == (t.Metadata as SIFTEscalationMetadata).CleanedAddress.Id))).ToArrayAsync();
```

is becoming this:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[TicketId] AS [TicketId], 
    [Project1].[TicketType] AS [TicketType], 
    [Project1].[Opened] AS [Opened], 
    [Project1].[Closed] AS [Closed], 
    [Project1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
    [Project1].[EscalationStatusText] AS [EscalationStatusText], 
    [Project1].[QualificationStatusText] AS [QualificationStatusText], 
    [Project1].[ProductsText] AS [ProductsText], 
    [Project1].[Cancelled] AS [Cancelled], 
    [Project1].[CancellationReason_Id] AS [CancellationReason_Id], 
    [Project1].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id], 
    [Project1].[Metadata_Id] AS [Metadata_Id], 
    [Project1].[NotesContainer_Id] AS [NotesContainer_Id]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[TicketId] AS [TicketId], 
        [Extent1].[TicketType] AS [TicketType], 
        [Extent1].[Opened] AS [Opened], 
        [Extent1].[Closed] AS [Closed], 
        [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified], 
        [Extent1].[EscalationStatusText] AS [EscalationStatusText], 
        [Extent1].[QualificationStatusText] AS [QualificationStatusText], 
        [Extent1].[ProductsText] AS [ProductsText], 
        [Extent1].[Cancelled] AS [Cancelled], 
        [Extent1].[CancellationReason_Id] AS [CancellationReason_Id], 
        [Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id], 
        [Extent1].[Metadata_Id] AS [Metadata_Id], 
        [Extent1].[NotesContainer_Id] AS [NotesContainer_Id], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[TicketMetadataID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE '2X0X' END AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Tickets] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TicketMetadata] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Discriminator] = N'SIFTEscalationMetadata') AND ([Extent1].[Metadata_Id] = [Extent2].[TicketMetadataID])
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE ([Project1].[C1] LIKE '2X0X%') AND (( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            486524 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486525 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486526 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable3]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508376 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable4]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508377 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable5]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508378 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable6]) AS [UnionAll5]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent3].[Address_Id] AS [Address_Id], 
            '2X0X' AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[TicketMetadata] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE ([Extent3].[Discriminator] = N'SIFTEscalationMetadata') AND ([Project1].[Metadata_Id] = [Extent3].[TicketMetadataID]) ) AS [Project8] ON 1 = 1
        WHERE [UnionAll5].[C1] = (CASE WHEN ([Project8].[C1] LIKE '2X0X%') THEN [Project8].[Address_Id] END)
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            486524 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable7]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486525 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable8]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486526 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable9]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508376 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable10]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508377 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable11]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508378 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable12]) AS [UnionAll10]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent4].[AddressEntered_Id] AS [AddressEntered_Id], 
            '2X0X' AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[TicketMetadata] AS [Extent4]
            WHERE ([Extent4].[Discriminator] = N'SIFTEscalationMetadata') AND ([Project1].[Metadata_Id] = [Extent4].[TicketMetadataID]) ) AS [Project16] ON 1 = 1
        WHERE [UnionAll10].[C1] = (CASE WHEN ([Project16].[C1] LIKE '2X0X%') THEN [Project16].[AddressEntered_Id] END)
    )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT 
            486524 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable13]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486525 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable14]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            486526 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable15]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508376 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable16]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508377 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable17]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT 
            508378 AS [C1]
            FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable18]) AS [UnionAll15]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent5].[CleanedAddress_Id] AS [CleanedAddress_Id], 
            '2X0X' AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[TicketMetadata] AS [Extent5]
            WHERE ([Extent5].[Discriminator] = N'SIFTEscalationMetadata') AND ([Project1].[Metadata_Id] = [Extent5].[TicketMetadataID]) ) AS [Project24] ON 1 = 1
        WHERE [UnionAll15].[C1] = (CASE WHEN ([Project24].[C1] LIKE '2X0X%') THEN [Project24].[CleanedAddress_Id] END)
    )))
```

What is the best way to get EF to generate a better query here? It would be nice if it could just do:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE Address_Id in(486524, 486525, 486526, 508376, 508377, 508378)
      OR AddressEntered_Id in(486524, 486525, 486526, 508376, 508377, 508378)
      OR CleanedAddress_Id in(486524, 486525, 486526, 508376, 508377, 508378)
```

Comment: Does `Contains()` produce better SQL? `addresses.Contains((t.Metadata as SIFTEscalationMetadata).Address.Id) || ...` For small sets of data I've seen EF5 generate a short `IN ()` when using `Contains`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Cory pointed out `Contains` extension method is translated to `IN` in SQL, so you should use it instead of `Any` which is translated to an `EXIST`:

```
return await _tickets.OfType<SIFTEscalationMetadata>()
                     .Where(t =>addesses.Contains(t.Address.Id) ||
                               addesses.Contains(t.AddressEntered.Id) ||
                               addesses.Contains(t.CleanedAddress.Id)).ToArrayAsync();
```

And also you should use `OfType` extension method to get only `SIFTEscalationMetadata` entities

Comment: Alas, it seems that a _ticket is not a SIFTEscaltionMetaData, but that a _ticket has a propertye MetaData of which some are SIFTEscalatnionMetaData and possibly some are not. Your OfType does not check if property t.MetaData has the correct type, bus if t is the correct type.

Comment: Yeah, the actual code I ended up with is a little different, but using Contains did work. I think it's strange that EF chooses to use an exists when checking .Any(...) of an array of integers, but it is what it is...

Answer (score 0):

From your code example I assume the following.

_tickets is a sequence of items of a class, let's say a Ticket. and each item in your sequence has a property MetaData. The returned value of MetaData may or may not be a SIFTEscalationMetaData. (is this true? or is every MetaData a SIFTEscalationMetaData?)

When the value of property MetaData is a SIFTEscalationMetaData, you are certain that property Ticket.MetaData has at least three other non-null properties: Address, AddressEntered and CleanedAddress. Furthermore you are certain that these three properties don't return NULL, and that they all three have a property Id.

Furthermore you also have a sequence addesses, where each element is of the same type as property Id. I don't know the type of Id, but let's assume it's IdType, probably an int or a string or the like

Apparently you wan't only those Tickets from your _tickets sequence where property MetaData is a SIFTEscalationMetaData, and at least one of the Id values of Ticket.MetaData.Address, Ticket.MetaData.AddressEntered or Ticke.MetaData.CleanedAddress is in the collection of addesses.

```
IEnumerable<Ticket> result = _tickets
    // first remember the ticket and convert the MetaData
    // to either null or a SIFTEscalationMetadata
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Ticket = t,
        MetaData = t.Metadata as SIFTEscalationMetadata,
    })
    // now take only those tickets where the metadata is not null
    .Where(t => t.MetaData != null)
    // and select from the remaining tickets the Ids you want to check
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Ticket = t.Ticket,
        Ids = new IdType[]
        {
            t.MetaData.Address.Id,
            t.MetaDate.AddressEntered.Id,
            t.MetaData.CleanedAddress.Id,
        },
     })
     // now take only those items where the intersection of the Ids and 
     // addesses has any elements
     .Where(t => addess.Interset(t.Ids).Any())
     .Select(t => t.Ticket);
```

The optimization is in the intermediate Select to anonymous types. The anonymous types will become SQL variables. The conversion to SIFTEscalationMetaData is done only once per ticket. Checking if any of the Ids is in addesses is done only once and only for the tickets that have the correct MetaData.

Comment: I'll have to run this through the profiler and see what it spits out. Could be interesting. Using contains as noted above already dropped the query time from unacceptable to acceptable (2+ seconds down to fractions of a second).

Comment: So I did just test this out; using Contains and leaving the various as castings in turns out to be a fair bit faster. Both methods result in the same number of reads, but the in(...) that contains generates finishes in 360ms while this method here takes about 530ms.